# Do I need OD/OC/OV Protection for Small LiPo Batteries with a Protection PCB already?

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, battery-charging, circuit-protection

I'm building a small design that is designed to only take smaller LiPo packs, those that often terminate in a JST PH 2.0 connector with example below:

[image]

It seems like most of these similar batteries I find online already include some form of protection circuitry in the PCB behind the Kapton tape. Currently, my design includes a [FS312F-G battery protection IC](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811151452_Fortune-Semicon-FS312F-G_C82736.pdf) in series, for overdischarge, overcurrent, and overvoltage protection.

Will this IC interfere with the protection already on the batteries in any meaningful way? If not, can I just get rid of this IC entirely instead, if the onboard protection PCB already does the same thing?

---

It's important to note that in the physical design, there is almost no physical way for a user to actually connect an unprotected 18650 [or other common cell], unless they go about soldering a JST connector on and dremel out a large hole for one. If that battery blows up, that's on them-problem and don't want to increase BOM cost for unintended use cases.

Comment: if you don't need system integration with the error conditions, you don't need to duplicate. It can sometimes be handy to eg, log and count UVP events to warn of a worn battery.

Comment: The protection circuitry has already those features except OLP: It stops discharging if the battery voltage drops below a certain value (UVP) and it stops charging if the battery voltage exceeds a certain value (OCP and OVP).

Comment: @dandavis I don't need to log that at all, since it's just powering a small circuit that won't have the complexity for monitoring that anyways.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Seems like I'm just missing overcurrent protection then, which I can probably just add using a small PTC in series. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good safety practice that you should always have at least an extra layer of protection when dealing with Li-ion batteries.

A proper design shall have:

1. A well designed, robust charging and discharging circuit
2. A battery protection circuit
3. A battery with protection circuit built-in

#3 would be the last resort in case both 1 & 2 failed.

You can easily find many designs in China skipped #2, and some I have came across even without #3 *and* a poorly designed #1, *and* with a crappy power supply. Not too difficult to imagine how these would ended up after being used for a while.

Comment: Thanks! I've honestly seen so many boards just omit #2, so I figured that I might as well save BOM costs too. Thinking about it more though, as you mentioned, missing #3 and bad #1 would be a big problem, so I'm gonna go ahead and keep it in just in case...